# Can my custom mapping using reflection be faster?

Tags: c#, caching, reflection, orm, mapping

I have the following method which maps a source object onto a duplicate destination object. However only certain properties marked with a specific attribute need to be mapped onto the new object.

My mapper currently looks as follows:

```
public static class BaseObjectExtensions
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Attribute[]> AttributeCache = new Dictionary<string, Attribute[]>();
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo[]> PropertyCache = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo[]>();

    public static void Map(this IBaseObject destination, IBaseObject source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var t = source.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties;
        lock (PropertyCache)
        {
            if (!PropertyCache.TryGetValue(t.FullName, out properties))
            {
                properties = t.GetProperties();
                PropertyCache.Add(t.FullName, properties);
            }
        }

        lock (AttributeCache)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
            {
                Attribute[] attrs;
                string k = t.FullName + prop;
                if (!AttributeCache.TryGetValue(k, out attrs))
                {
                    attrs = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(prop);
                    AttributeCache.Add(k, attrs);
                }

                if (attrs.OfType<DatabaseMap>().Any())
                {
                    prop.SetValue(destination, prop.GetValue(source));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This map can either be used on a single item or a collection of items. I noticed a performance bottleneck so after much research I added in the two caches. Times are as follows for large collections of items:

- Without reflection cache: 26.6 seconds
- With reflection cache (ConcurrentDictionary): 31 seconds
- With reflection cache (locking): 4 seconds

The speedup is dramatic, but I think it could still be better. After a lot of reading I've found things like [FastInvoke](http://flurfunk.sdx-ag.de/2012/05/c-performance-bei-der-befullungmapping.html) and [another FastInvoke](https://code.google.com/p/somemethods/source/browse/trunk/DotNet/Dotnet.Invoke/FastInvoke.cs?r=37) but cannot seem to apply them to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Is there anything else I can potentially do to speed this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that for the best performance You should compile mapper using Reflection.Emit, or use one of already existing: [Emit mapper vs valueinjecter or automapper performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053590/emit-mapper-vs-valueinjecter-or-automapper-performance)

Comment: Holy crap EmitMapper is fast! Now in the milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this,

rather than processing all properties in turn and then checking for the existence of your attribute - just get the properties that have your attribute:

```
var props = from p in this.GetType().GetProperties()
            let attr = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DatabaseMap), true)
            where attr.Length == 1
            select new { Property = p, Attribute = attr.First() as DatabaseMap};
```

at this point you only have those properties in the object that are marked with your attribute.

Comment: I tried this and removed my attribute cache. The result of the operation above is then cached. The speed improvement went from 4 seconds to about 1.4 seconds.