# Inline mapping settings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I need to map domain objects to DTO objects in my SPA, built on Angular and WebAPI. For this feature I have decided to use some auto-mapping tool. During my mapping I need to provide some contextual information which extends me global mapping settings. In fact I want to implement this:

```
int i = 10;
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(src, opt => {
    opt.BeforeMap((src, dest) => src.Value = src.Value + i);
    opt.AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Name = HttpContext.Current.Identity.Name);
});
```

This is **Automapper** code. But I do not want to use Atomapper because it is very slow.

I have looked through other tools like (**Mapster**, **ExpressMapper**). This tools are cool and quick, but they do not support inline settings as far as I know.

Can somebody advice me some other automapping tool, which supports this feature. Or maybe somebody gove me advice, how to implement this with one of the mentioned tools?

Comment: The reason why AutoMapper is slow is because of the exact feature you're highlighting right now. Those features are expensive, and make things slower.

Answer (score 0):

[ValueInjecter](https://github.com/omuleanu/ValueInjecter) can create custom maps:

```
Mapper.AddMap<Customer, CustomerInput>(src =>
{
    var res = new CustomerInput();
    res.InjectFrom(src); // maps properties with same name and type
    res.FullName = src.FirstName + " " + src.LastName;
    return res;
});
```

[EmitMapper](http://emitmapper.codeplex.com/wikipage) has a `PostProcess` method:

```
var mapper = ObjectMapperManager
    .DefaultInstance
    .GetMapper<Source, Destination>(
        new DefaultMapConfig()
        .PostProcess<Destination>( (destination, state) => { destination.list.Sort(); return destination;} )
    );
```

If AutoMapper is too slow for you then EmitMapper adaptation maybe a good choice. Look on this benchmark: [Emit mapper vs valueinjecter or automapper performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053590/emit-mapper-vs-valueinjecter-or-automapper-performance).

Unfortunately EmitMapper is abandonded years ago.

Comment: Thank you.  It is real trouble.  Maybe you know some techniques to implement this with handwritten mapping?  I mean automatically map part of the object,  and map the rest by myself.  Can you suggest some convenient way to do this

Comment: @Stalso, you may use `FastMapper` for auto-map part. Or similar tool which is much faster than AutoMapper and stills alive. Then leave another part handwritten and write a wrapper for combining these two parts, like `MyMapper.Map(source, dest)`. Sorry if it is an obvious advice.

Comment: Yes it is obvious.) Yet, thank you. I have implemented some tecnique with Mapster and I will publish it, after I test it.