# Is there a way use the EmitMapper in .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, dto

[EmitMapper](https://emitmapper.codeplex.com/) is work fine in classic .net framework, but it does't work in the .net core, and I can't find a version for .net core, is any way can to do this?

I don't like use the System.Reflection to do this, it's too slow.

Comment: What about using other alternatives?

Comment: automapper is a alternative, but it's too slow, this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053590/emit-mapper-vs-valueinjecter-or-automapper-performance) is performance compare between emit mapper and automapper.

Comment: .NET Core builds its environment, therefore you should not stick to third party libraries that you used to use in old .NET projects. You may want to check out new libraries such as: https://github.com/edwardmeng/PowerMapper There is also a benchmark table for comparison.

Comment: It's looks nice, thanks, I'm trying to use it.